# PHP form not working, although done everything right

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make PHP form, it is sending me success message but I am not recieving any mail, tried everything but no use.
Heres the my main PHP code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // hide all basic notices from PHP

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // require a name from user
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
        $nameError =  'Forgot your name!'; 
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }

    // require a name from user
    if(trim($_POST['phone']) === '') {
        $phoneError =  'Forgot your contact!'; 
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    }

    // need valid email
    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Forgot to enter in your e-mail address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    // we need at least some content
    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
        $commentError = 'You forgot to enter a message!';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
        }
    }

    // upon no failure errors let's email now!
    if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $emailTo = 'engr.hussainraza@live.com';
        $subject = 'MATHESON FIRST AID: ENQUIRY FORM SUBMISSION '.$name;
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

and here is my HTML code, please note that I have made the script and the form on the same page and is therefore, embedded in HTML as well, here goes the form HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>hussain</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="wrapper_main">

            <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) {
                include 'success.html';
            } else { ?>

            <div id="content">
                <section class="section_right">
                    <img src="images/right2.png"   alt="" title="" />
                </section>
                <div class="main_content">
                    <h1>Enquiry Form</h1><br/>
                    <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError) ) { ?>
                        <p class="alert">Error submitting the form</p>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="form_wrap2">
                        <form id="contact-us" action="enquiry.php" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" placeholder="Enter your name" />
                                <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                                <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $nameError;?></span> 
                                <?php } ?>

                                <label for="title">Company</label>
                                <input name="title" type="text" id="company" placeholder="Enter your company name" />

                                <label for="address">Address:</label>
                                <input name="address" type="text" id="address" placeholder="Enter your address" />

                                <label for="tel">Telephone:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['phone'])) echo $_POST['phone'];?>" placeholder="Enter your telephone number" />
                                <?php if($phoneError != '') { ?>
                                <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $phoneError;?></span> 
                                <?php } ?>

                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
                                <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                                <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <label for="business">Type of Business:</label>
                                <input name="bussiness" type="text" id="business" placeholder="Enter type of business" />

                                <label for="enquiry">Enquiry:</label>
                                <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" id="comments" placeholder="Enter comments here" ><?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>
                                <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                                <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $commentError;?></span> 
                                <?php } ?>

                                <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- content end -->

  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#contact-us').submit(function() {
            $('form#contact-us .error').remove();
            var hasError = false;
            $('.requiredField').each(function() {
                if($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Your forgot to enter your '+labelText+'.</span>');
                    $(this).addClass('inputError');
                    hasError = true;
                } else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                    if(!emailReg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {
                        var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                        $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Sorry! You\'ve entered an invalid '+labelText+'.</span>');
                        $(this).addClass('inputError');
                        hasError = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            if(!hasError) {
                var formInput = $(this).serialize();
                $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
                    $('form#contact-us').slideUp("fast", function() {                  
                        $(this).before('<p class="tick"><strong>Thanks!</strong> Your email has been delivered. Huzzah!</p>');
                    });
                });
            }

            return false;   
        });
    });
    //-->!]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say you have tried EVERYTHING??  --> http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Instead of manually setting `$emailSent = true;`, you should start by checking the return value of the `mail()` function.

Comment: Don't turn off error reporting! Read this: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of notices:

1. Don't disable error_reporting untill you go to production. It will spill out what might going wrong, or you shouldn't be doing. You might want to do it anyway, therefore you can put an @ before the command that triggers the error.
2. Instead of `trim($_POST['contactName'] == ''` use `empty($_POST['contactName'])`. Advantage of this is that is checks automatic if the value isset. If you don't want an empty space as input, use both.
3. Instead of `!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email'])`, you can use the simple PHP built-in function `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`.
4. `$headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;` is an invalid header, as you specify no name. Use `$headers = 'From: ' . $emailTo . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;`. See for valid headers http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (to paramater)

General advice to initialize the variables of your script in the top of it. That way you only have to check and trim (?) your input all the time, but only have to do it once and assign it to a safe variable.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's mail function runs off of sendmail on your server. It is most likely not installed and/or not running.